# exception handling mistake

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a condition for accepting only a negative value for a variable and it should also not raise a value error.
My code goes like this ->

```
try:
    x = int(input("Enter -ve value : "))
    while x >= 0:
        print("Error wrong value!")
        x = int(input("Enter -ve value : " )
except ValueError:
    print("Error wrong value!")
    x = int(input("Enter -ve value : "))
    while x >= 0:
        print("Error wrong value!")
        x=int(input("Enter -ve value : " )
```

The only problem with this approach is that, suppose I press enter without entering a value for the first time. It takes me to the "except" condition and it works fine but if I enter a blank value again my code stops because of value error. How do I stop this from happening? Is there a more efficient way of writing this code without importing any modules?

Thank you for your time and efforts! I wrote this question on the mobile app so sorry if it causes any inconvenience!

Comment: @Isma I am sorry but I am quite new so if you could demonstrate that it would be awesome!

Comment: Your `try..except` splits the entire routine into two separate parts. You want one `while` with the `try..except` inside, not as an outer control loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
x = 0
while x >= 0:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter -ve value : "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error wrong value!")
        x = 0
```

This will achieve what you are asking for in that it will keep prompting you to enter a number `while x >= 0` and will also ensure the exception handling is always carried out on each input too.